# Can I use ENVI Classic to process JWST tiff image?

Tags: james-webb-space-telescope, image-processing

I am interested to process JWST or any other astronomical images. Can I use ENVI Classic to process it? I have some JWST tiff images and I would like to know about the gasses, compounds, the brightness of stars, or anything. I am not sure about which tools I have to use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since ENVI Classic appears to be a tool for processing GIS images (e.g. satellite images of the surface of the Earth), it is not useful for astronomical data, any more than it would be useful for X-ray medical imaging.